# Installing and booting Ubuntu with UEFI?

Tags: grub2, virtualbox, uefi, secure-boot

OK, so... What is it supposed to look like when I install Ubuntu with UEFI turned on? Is this supposed to automatically work, or do I need to select an option somewhere?

I've tried this several times - once on my laptop and once in Virtual Box with EFI turned on, and every time I install Ubuntu with Secure Boot turned on, Ubuntu fails in the install when trying to install GRUB. Then, when I reboot there is no bootable medium because GRUB wasn't installed. Also, when I go back and try to install GRUB manually, I fail.

What do I need to do for a smooth install of Ubuntu with secure boot enabled? I apologize if this is documented somewhere obvious, but I haven't been able to find it so far.

Comment: What brand/model system? Are you partitioning in advance and creating an ESP - efi system partition (FAT32 with boot flag)? Or dual booting with Windows?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI A few systems lock an ESP in UEFI settings, or have a corrupt ESP that needs repairs.

Comment: It's an HP laptop with an i7 and 32 GB of RAM. There's no hard drive issues. I'm using a newly created VirtualBox VM with 20 GB of hard drive space. I'm not partititioning in advance, and I'm not dual-booting.

Comment: Do not know enough about details of VM type installs. there is this older thread but not UEFI Secure Boot. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2172199&p=13104689#post13104689

Comment: Thanks! I guess it still doesn't answer my question, then: Is there some way that Ubuntu is capable of automatically installing with Secure Boot turned on?

Comment: It used to just work as long as you did not need proprietary drivers. I believe now it will install proprietary drivers, but then you install your on Secure key for that application. You have to boot installer in the boot mode you want, UEFI with Secure Boot, UEFI, or CSM/BIOS/Legacy boot modes. Then you have to have installed system in that same boot mode. Do not know if VM installs work with Secure Boot?